# Vue3 is it possible to change the data given by provide->inject from child's end?

Tags: vue.js, state, data-visualization

As written in the subject,

in vue,

provide is used for passing data from parent to child.

and child element gets the data by inject.

as @emit does, is it also possible to modify data
given by "provide" in child element?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a component could `provide` a `ref` that gets updated by a descendant that `inject`s it:

```js
// App.vue
export default {
  setup() {
    const counter = ref(0)
    provide('counter', counter)
  }
}

// ComponentA.vue
export default {
  setup() {
    const counter = inject('counter')

    return {
      counter,
      increment: () => counter.value++  // updates App.counter
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/updating-provided-values-in-vue-3-f5l7s?file=/src/App.vue)

However, the [Vue docs recommend also `provide`-ing an update method](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#mutating-reactive-properties), keeping the mutation and state co-located:

```js
// App.vue
export default {
  setup() {
    const counter = ref(0)
    provide('counter', counter)
    provide('increment', () => counter.value++)
  }
}

// ComponentA.vue
export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      counter: inject('counter'),
      increment: inject('increment'),
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/updating-provided-values-in-vue-3-forked-cmonj?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: As an addition, let me say that the `increment` would be good to be co-named like `counterIncrement`, so you know exactly what you will increment. It gets messy in a big projects 

Comment: Does this work with options API? I tried using computed and ref but the parent just wont update.

Comment: @TimarIvoBatis did you make it work using options API?